# How can I use ajax jquery to redirect to another page controller action

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, phalcon

How does one use ajax to redirect to another controller action with parameters `id` and `name` but without those parameters being displayed in the url?

```
<form class="bisForm" id="bisForm" name="bisForm" method="post">
  <div class="contentOne">
    {% for index, b in bis|json_decode %}
      <input class="button-primary toBis" type="button" value={{ b }} id={{ "bis_"~index }}>
    {% endfor %}
  </div> </form>

  $(document).ready(function(){     
    $('.toBis').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var bisId   = event.currentTarget.id;
      var bisName = event.currentTarget.value;

      //console.log(bisName.serialize());
      $.ajax({
        // contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: "post",
        url: "/bis/content/",
        data: {name: bisName, id: bisId},
        //data: "name="+ bisName+"&id="+ bisId,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        //dataType: 'json',
        //data: "name="+bisName,
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        error: function(response){
          if(!response)
            alert("Server Error");
          },
        success: function(data){
          //console.log(data);
          //window.location.href = '/bis/content/';
        }
      });

      return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: <form class="bisForm" id="bisForm" name="bisForm" method="post">
            <div class="contentOne">
                   <input class="button-primary toBis" type="button" value="bis1" id="bis_1">

            </div>
</form>

Comment: use the `edit`-button to add something to your question

Comment: Yes, got that. Then you need one more **Ajax-post** in success of your main Ajax call. And post the parameters to '/bis/content/'. Thanks.

Comment: hello,
how i can do that do you have an example plz ?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use AJAX to post the data, simply submit the form. Have a hidden field and assign clicked buttons ID and VALUE to it just before submitting the form 
(also have action attribute for form to submit data). Like,

```
<form class="bisForm" id="bisForm" name="bisForm" method="post" action="/bis/content/">
  <div class="contentOne">
    {% for index, b in bis|json_decode %}
      <input class="button-primary toBis" type="button" value={{ b }} id={{ "bis_"~index }}>
     <input type="hidden" name="clickedItem" id="clickedItem" value="" />
    {% endfor %}
  </div> </form>
```

In JavaScript Code, make these changes,

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    $('.toBis').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var bisId   = event.currentTarget.id;
      var bisName = event.currentTarget.value;      
      $('#clickedItem').attr('value', bisId +'$'+ bisName); // assign value here
      $('#bisForm').submit(); // submit the form
      return false;
    });
  });
```

And in your controller action, take the sbmitted hidden value, split it by '$' and use them as you want.

```
[httppost]
public ActionResult content(string clickedItem)
{
  string[] clickedItems = clickedItem.split('$');
  string id = clickedItems[0].toString();
  string value = clickedItems[1].toString();
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in 'success' of you ajax call:

```
 success: function(data) {
    var strUri = window.location.href;
    window.location.href = strUri.replace(window.location.pathname, '/bis/content/');
}
```

Hope it works. Thanks.

Comment: Thx, but when i go to the bis page i want to get all my parameters this is my problem so i want to see that in url homePage/bis/content/?
and in the controller action for bis where i can get my parameters name and id

Comment: maybe i make a mistake i want redirect when i click in this button to the url /bis/content/ like that and post my parameters without show them in my url how could i do that with Ajax and json

Comment: @chall, why don't you redirect directly from server-side code then? Use **RedirectToAction** and pass the parameters.

Comment: because i dont know how i can use it, just i want to redirect to this url /bis/content/ and posted my parameters name and id without show them in the url for a mode security so, i need a solution :)